# Why are there multiple install commands on Anaconda Cloud?

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

When searching a package in Anaconda Cloud, there are often multiple commands one could use to install a package. For example,

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge xxx 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 xxx 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 xxx
```

**What's the difference between them?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Labels

Channel maintainers have an option to add [labels](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/glossary/#cloud-glossary-label) to their package builds. Anaconda Cloud suggests using labels as [a tool for organizing the development cycle](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/user-guide/tutorials/#using-labels-in-the-development-cycle).  What the labels mean is totally up to the channel maintainer, so there's no general answer that will cover it all.  When a label isn't provided, then default `main` is assigned.

Only advanced users should ever need to use a label. Most users should simply use the default specification:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge xxx
```

### Example: `gcc7`

Let's look at a specific use case taken from your example. The `gcc7` label is used by the Conda Forge channel maintainers to designate packages that have been compiled under a different toolchain than the packages they provide under their `main` tag.  This `gcc7` toolchain is designed to more closely match that which is used by the official channels (what you'd get from `-c defaults`) and thereby yield binaries that are compatible.  You can read all about it in [this issue on the Conda Forge repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/616).

Comment: Is there a way to remove labels? As a owner/maintainer, I have no idea how the extra (stale) label appeared here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/stumpy

Comment: @slaw looks like you can specify labels ([see Conda Forge docs](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/conda_forge_yml.html#channels)), but I don't see anything for removing them. I also don't see any "stale" label on your package; only the "main" label (default) and the one tagging packages built with the pre-March 2020 build stack ("cf202003").