# why conda doesn't find file and puts anaconda search -t conda websockets

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

conda doesn't find the module with the command ***conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 websockets***

and put's error:

```
Fetching package metadata: ......
Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: websockets

Did you mean one of these?

    webassets, rb-em-websocket, pockets

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda websockets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "`linux-armv7l`" shown in the error, it appears that this is for an ARM-based platform, which is unfortunately not officially supported by any organization (e.g., Anaconda, Conda Forge, etc.), and one of the main community-contributed channels ([**rpi**](https://anaconda.org/rpi) maintained by [jjhelmus](https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda)) for providing **linux-armv7l**-compatible package builds went inactive about 18 months ago. There is [an open thread on the berryconda repo](https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda/issues/83) discussing its future and alternative options. In tragic summary: **there is no channel that has a `websockets` package for this platform**, hence the error.

As a side note, the additional labels that are provided when viewing a package on Anaconda Cloud (e.g., `conda-forge/label/cf202003`) have very specific purposes, and are rarely ever needed by most users (instead just use `-c conda-forge`). See the question, "[Why are there multiple install commands on Anaconda Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57571032/570918)" for more details.

Comment: so miniconda with a rasberry pi is not usefull

Comment: @raphael from the repo thread it seems like people who really want it do it through Docker.